# Convert specified items from enum to list?

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following item in my enum list

```
public enum Role
    {
        ED=1,
        CPDHEAD=2,
        CPD=3,
        CENTERMANAGER=4,
        ACCOUNTSHEAD=5,
        MANAGER=6,
        TECHNICALHEAD=7,
        SALESINDIVIDUAL=8,
        ACCOUNTS=9,
        TECHNICALINDIVIDUAL=10
    }
```

How can I get `TechnicalHead` and `TechnicalIndividual` values into `List<int>`

This is what I've tried but it returns all the values from the enum role

```
 List<int> _empRolelId = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumClass.Role))
                                .Cast<int>()                                    
                                .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Here the problem is I am getting all the values from `Enum Role`.I want only `Technical lHead and Technical Individual` values ie `7&10`

Comment: `Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))` is *redundant* in the light of previous `.Cast<int>()`

Comment: Side note: when you define value for enum item. if the values are consecutive  you dont need specify values for all items. just set `ED = 1,` and next items will get their values in consecutive  form.

Answer (score 7):

Your enum's underlying type is `int`, so its items can be converted to `int` explicitly like this:

```
var _empRolelId = new List<int>();
_empRolelId.Add((int)Role.TECHNICALHEAD);
_empRolelId.Add((int)Role.TECHNICALINDIVIDUAL);
```

or build the list when intializing:

```
var _empRoleId = new List<int>
{
    (int)Role.TECHNICALHEAD,
    (int)Role.TECHNICALINDIVIDUAL
};
```

Comment: This is what I would prefer, unless the point was to play with enums and Linq

Answer (score 4):

You can filter with a where clause. Also, the select is redundant since you cast as int earlier.

```
List<int> _empRolelId = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumClass.Role))
                            .Cast<int>()
                            .Where(x => x ==  (int)Rextester.Role.TECHNICALHEAD || x == (int)Rextester.Role.TECHNICALINDIVIDUAL)
                            .ToList();
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CRP93760)

Comment: Think it would be much better if you didn't use magic numbers and used the enums

Comment: I tried to modify Your demo, to skip magic const and move the where before the cast. Didn't work. Array can't have Where